# Can the car or the bike travel further?

Tags: calculation-puzzle

There is a car and a motor-bike. The car and the bike both have an spare tire. Now, the car has a total of 5 tyres (one spare tire included) and the bike has a total of 3 tires (one spare tire included).

Each tire of the bike and the car will last for **100 KMs**. Take the following points into consideration:

- The tire will not have any puncture or problem
- The tire will rotate only when the vehicle moves.
- Assume that petrol/diesel is infinite.
- You cannot buy new tire.
- Tires can be changed easily.
- Once a tire has been used for travelling 100 KM, it cannot be used again.

Can the car or the bike travel further?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is this a trick question? It look just to be a math problem.

Answer:

> The bike can travel further.

How to travel with bike:

> The bike can travel `150 km = 100 km / 2 * 3` by rotating between its wheels. For each 50 km, two of the three wheels are used, so each wheel it used for two of the intervals.

How to travel with car:

> The car can travel `125 km = 100 km / 4 * 5` by using a different four of the five wheels for each of five 25 km segments.

Alternative short argument:

> Alternatively, the spare tire is a +1/4 relative increase in tire-power for the car and a +1/2 for the bike, so the bike wins.

Comment: The bike can also travel on one tire.  ;)

Comment: @Harv And the car on 2 ;c) (...as proven in some movies...)

Comment: @Xnor: I *think* it is *just* a math's puzzle. It may be rather easy,  but I think it is a valid puzzle never-the-less and to be taken seriously. (The bike requires the 'change half-way' *trick* to be thought of.) Please put your answer in spoiler tags.

Comment: The case with the motorcycle is similar to making three pieces of toast toasted on both sides with a toaster that can only toast two pieces one-sidedly at any one time.